# css3 Media queries are working on browser resize but on my iphone they doesn't seem to work

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive-design

I'm building my WordPress blog (doing the css with scss).
I've created media queries for all types for browser sizes which you can see here: 
http://pastie.org/3846370

And when I resize my laptop's browser they work perfectly fine. However, When I go and test the site on my Iphone they just don't see to work.

I should also mention that I did include the right meta tag in the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you got a link to the webpage you're testing? It'll be easier to debug any issues with the full picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I solved this.

The issue was that I was loading the smallest device's media query first and the biggest in the end and this should be the other way around. 
You should start from the biggest device width and end with the smallest one.

Also the you should remove the min-width property and only leave the max-width.

Comment: I am facing same problem, but your solution seem not work for me, my android phone still viewing the original size, not the setted  media queries size.
Can you write your full code here?